# CSS layout, middle column is fixed-width AND positioned, two outer columns fluid width, no spacing

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container element which must hold 3 divs (or table cells or flexboxes, or whatever). The container is fixed size. Let's say 500px width, 100px height.

The middle div must be fixed width, say 100px. It must also be able to be moved around by setting the css. For this example, let's say it is fixed at 225 pixels from the left.

The two remaining divs should fill up the remaining space on each side (or take up no space when there's no room, even if the middle div is moved past the boundary of the container). There should be no space between the side divs and the middle div, nor should there be any overlap between the side divs and the middle div.

All the innner divs are 100% height (i.e. 100px).

```
container 500x100
----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| |-------------------------------| |---------------------| |-------------| |  
| |  left, fluid                  | | middle, positioned  | | right,fluid | |
| |                               | |at 225px, 100px width| |             | | 
| |-------------------------------| |---------------------| |-------------| | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: I think JS is necessary, unfortunately :(

Comment: For slightly more context, the middle element will be able to be moved around using javascript, so preferrably a solution will not have a dozen properties (at 225px here) to be changed repeatedly.

Comment: Can you please explain the `even if the middle div is moved past the boundary of the container` part?

Comment: Not really following you on this one... Could you explain it in a bit more detail.

Comment: Also as far as I know the layout isn't possible via `CSS`. You can have the sides fixed with the center fluid, if that's any use to you.

Comment: @andyb
I will be moving the middle element around (left or right) with javascript. This could move the element to large negative or positive numbers, which would put it "offscreen". I just don't want anything too funky to happen in that case :)

Comment: @Ruddy
If you tell me what parts to clarify I'd be happy to... The center is fixed width, and set to a particular X coordinate inside the container. The two sides are fluid and take the remaining space.

Comment: @daniellewallace So what have you tried for this? If you could create a JSFiddle that would be helpful. I don't think anyone will create this code for you, this site is to help you with existing code not create it for you.

Comment: @Ruddy
I spent a great deal of time trying a number of solutions, including floated divs, flex divs, absolute and relative postioning, tables, and other things. None of them worked so I don't see the point of putting up a failed solution that is likely barking up the wrong tree entirely (i.e. a partial table solution when the answer is display:flex). I understand it may be too much work to put up a full solution but I just don't have a starting point I know will get there. I would accept text explaining what to do and implement it myself.

Comment: @daniellewallace So is this kinda like a slider type thing? if the middle div is more to the left then the right div will be bigger? What is this doing (meant for)?

Comment: @Ruddy
It's just a dynamic UI element. It will be sliding around on its own when the user does certain things. Let's say for the purprose of this example that it tries to follow the X coordinate of the mouse or something like that.

Comment: @daniellewallace I had a little mess about with an idea I had, is this any good to you? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/khsMh/) I did this pretty fast and so its glitchy etc but may help you.

Comment: @Ruddy Thanks! :)
I was hoping there was a way to do something more css-based, but if I can't I will probably end up doing something similar instead. Here's that fiddle with a little less glitch :) http://jsfiddle.net/rU4BA/

Comment: @daniellewallace Via CSS I don't see a way it can be done. And np, we could make it stop at the sides etc but looks good. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Ruddy : hello mate :) .....its possible via `calc` and `css-tables`...though its not cross browser!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor Hey buddy, cross browser is a very important thing these days tho. But nice job!

Comment: @Ruddy : actually question was tagged CSS3 and FLEX, so i assumed old-browser support is not that important!

Comment: @NoobEditor That is true! xD

Answer (score 7):

Ever heard of [**`CSS Tables`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) and [**`calc`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)??

**Note :** This Solution is CSS3 compliant, so IE8 and below would not support this answer!! :)

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DzK26/1/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="cent">cent</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div { /* just for demo */
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid red
}
.container {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.left, .right, .cent {
    display:table-cell /*aabara-kaa-dabara*/
}
.cent {
    width:225px; /* fixed center */
}
.left, .right {
    width : calc(50% - 225px) /* make left and right divs fluid */
}
```

**EDIT**

In case u want center to give *feel* of moving around on rezise, you'll have to play with `adjacent div`s `width`...something like :

```
.left {
    width : calc(30% - 225px);
}

.right{
    width : calc(70% - 225px);
}
```

<kbd>[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DzK26/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Hmm, as you made the window smaller the center width becomes greater tho. So its not a fixed width?

Comment: center is fixed, it appears smaller because u are watching it in ratio of fluid sized div next to it....see this fiddle, it'll help u understand => http://jsfiddle.net/DzK26/2/ (*note that, not a single `a` comes to new line on resize* )

Comment: Yeah but the box changing width. (I haven't really look at the code because im at work and tired! I will check it out later if im wrong xD)

Comment: left and right are changing width...center is fixed width....check from home after having a redbull maybe..it'll give u wings!! ;)

Comment: Am I just high or something? That middle div is changing size. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/DzK26/5/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51286/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-ruddy)

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution relies on setting width of some elements. This does not enable the middle element to be positioned past the left boundary of the container box in any solution (as negative widths are not allowed by the property. This was implied when I said "even if the middle div is moved past the boundary of the container", but I probably should have been more explicit.

Comment: it should be width : calc(50% - 112.5px) by subtract 225 twice from total 100% ?

Answer (score 0):

If we use markup like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box1">a</div>
    <div class="wpr">
        <div class="box2">b</div>
        <div class="box3">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

..we can make use of block formatting contexts with overflow:hidden or overflow:auto to acheive this.

Hover over the container in the fiddle to see the effect

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/s78A6/6/)**

### CSS

```
.container{
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
}
.wpr {
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100px;
    background:aqua;
}
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
    height: 100px;
}
.box1 {
    background:pink;
    float:left;
    min-width: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: min-width 1s;
    -moz-transition: min-width 1s;
    -o-transition: min-width 1s;
    transition: min-width 1s;
}
.box2 {
    background:purple;
    width:100px; /*fixed width */
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.box3 {
    background:orange;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);  /*100px is same as box with fixed width */
}
.container:hover .box1 {
    min-width: 450px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution relies on setting width of some elements. This does not enable the middle element to be positioned past the left boundary of the container box in any solution (as negative widths are not allowed by the property. This was implied when I said "even if the middle div is moved past the boundary of the container", but I probably should have been more explicit.

Comment: @daniellewallace - take a look at my updated answer:  It dos NOT rely on setting widths on elements. (except for the middle box as per the question)

Comment: you are moving box2 by setting the width of box1. This does not enable box2 to be moved past the LEFT side of the container.

Answer (score -1):

This is simply possible via Table.
Create the table like this

```
<table class="container">
    <tr>
        <td class="box1">
        </td>
        <td class="box2">
        </td>
        <td class="box3">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Apply The CSS Like this :

```
.container{
    background:#dadada;
    width:500px;
    height:100px;
    border:none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.box1{
    background:red;
    width:100px; /* This will set the position of Middle Box as well as occupy the space in left */
}
.box2{
    background:blue;
    width:350px; /* This will set the width of Middle Box */
}
.box3{
    background:green;
    /*This will automatically occupy the space in the right */
}
```

You can find the Demo here : **http://jsfiddle.net/s78A6/**

Comment: u are still setting fixed width to 2 columns mate!! :)

Comment: He does but if you remove the `width:100px;` on `.box1` it should work. Updated his [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s78A6/3/). I now noticed that the middle box will always be exactly centered, that wasn't OP question..

Comment: I have no idea what this is, Lol. This is wrong so downvote from me.

Comment: @NoobEditor : Ruddy has said that there are two values for middle box. Position from left, and width. The position-left value of middle box can be given as a width of first box. This will push the box2 towards right and occupy the space.

Comment: @Rubby : Have you read the comments I've written in CSS ?
You want to set the LEFT-POSITION and FIXED-WIDTH of middle box.
I've set the FIXED-WIDTH of middle box. 

Now you want to give it LEFT-POSITION.
I've given this value as a WIDTH of first box.
This will PUSH the middle box to the value of LEFT-POSITION.

Now try to change the values either WIDTH or LEFT-POSITION (which is given as width of first box) of the middle box.
First and Last block will maintain the fluid layout while middle box will be of fixed width.

I think you need this only as your figure shows !

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution relies on setting width of some elements. This does not enable the middle element to be positioned past the left boundary of the container box in any solution (as negative widths are not allowed by the property. This was implied when I said "even if the middle div is moved past the boundary of the container", but I probably should have been more explicit.